# Using an invariant to determine the boundary conditions in a typical binary search problem

Tags: java, binary-search, invariants, loop-invariant

I am trying to solve the typical binary search question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-search/):

> Given a sorted (in ascending order) integer array nums of n elements and a target value, write a function to search target in nums. If target exists, then return its index, otherwise return -1.
> So for [-1,0,3,5,9,12], target = 9; the output is `4`.

As per [a solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-search/discuss/608498/Loop-invariant), the invariant used is:

> target is within nums[lo ... hi]

However, given this invariant, I am unsure how to determine the boundary conditions:

```java
class Solution {
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        // Loop invariant: target is within nums[lo ... hi] 
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mi = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (nums[mi] == target) {
                return mi;
            } else if (nums[mi] > target) {
                hi = mi - 1;
            } else {
                lo = mi + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How did the invariant help us determine:

a. `lo<=hi` instead of just `lo<hi` in the while loop condition? 
b. `hi=mi-1` instead of `hi=mi` in the else clause?
c. `lo=mi+1` instead of `lo=mi` in the else clause?

Personally, when I solved the question myself, I used the invariant as `a[lo]<=target<=a[hi]` based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569973/8305079), but I still had questions analogous to the three above.  Sure, I could take a few examples to understand what to do, but I am specifically focusing on [using invariants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393352/8305079) to determine what to do.

I am new to using invariants in binary search, so would appreciate any kind of help.  Thanks!

Comment: Not answering your question. It's my personal opinion, but it's much simpler to work in terms of half-intervals `[lo, hi)` (i.e. `lo <= index(target) < hi`). When you compare `nums[mi]` with target, if `target < nums[mi]`, then `hi := mi` (since `index(target) < mi`), else `lo := mi` (since `mi <+ index(target)`). Half-intervals are also useful in other settings (such as segment trees, range queries, etc.)

Comment: @Dmitry in your example, if `target < nums[mi]` then why `hi := mi`?  Why not `hi := mi-1`?

Comment: Because our invariant is `index(target) < hi`. You know that `index(target) < mi` (you've just determined that `target < nums[mi]`), and you don't know anything about `index(target)` vs `mi-1` (e.g. it can be the case that `target = nums[mi-1]`). Therefore, we set `hi := mi`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Thank you! :)

Comment: @Dmitry also one follow up - in your example, what would the conditional expression within the while loop (the termination condition) be?  `lo<=hi` or `lo<hi`?  My guess is, `lo<hi`, since `lo==hi` implies `target==hi` which breaks the invariant, correct?

Comment: `while (hi - lo > 1)`. You want to repeat the loop while there are at least two elements remaining in the interval, and the number of elements is `hi - lo`. I guess this `1` is the price to pay for getting rid of `+-1` everywhere else:)

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks again, Dmitry! :)