# While and Exit Condition in Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

1. With respect to the while loop to keep the search running `while (low <= high)`, is there any consensus if it's better to use a '<' or '<=' since I see instances of both online?
2. The exit conditions of some binary search templates differ in the sense that some of them use Style A where as soon as target equals the midpoint we return target. B, on the other hand, only happens after the while loop is exited and returns nums[low]. Is this just a matter of personal preference?

A. `if (target === nums[mid]) return target;`

B. `return nums[low]` after exiting while loop

Comment: It depends on the problem you're trying to solve. Finding an occurrence would use A, finding the first occurrence would use B

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations, but there isn't a nice long answer like @trincot's about this one specific facet

Comment: You may also enjoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564658/binary-search-and-invariant-relation/26569973#26569973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in the `while` condition comes from the difference in the meaning of `high`: sometimes it is the index *after* the last element that belongs to the range, and sometimes it represent the index of the last element itself. There is no consensus on which definition of `high` is to be used.

However, you could align this choice to how ranges are usually represented in the language environment you use. For instance, in Python, `range(a, b)` *excludes* `b`, and in JavaScript `arr.slice(a, b)` *excludes* `b` too. So in those languages I would go for a definition of `high` that excludes it from the range, and so your `while` condition would be `<`. In VBA there are `LBound` and `UBound`, which suggest an *inclusive* definition of `high`, and so the `while` condition would be `<=`.

Either way the `while` condition should reflect that the current range is non-empty.

The addition of this line in the loop

```
if (target === nums[mid]) return target;
```

...is another matter.

First of all, you would not return `target`, as that doesn't really help the caller (they already know the value of `target`, since they provided it). It is more appropriate to return the index where the value was found, so that the caller might act on that index:

```
if (target === nums[mid]) return mid;
```

For the same reasons, the alternative code would do:

```
return low;
```

On the one hand the first code variant offers a possibility to exit the loop early. In the extreme case we might even get lucky, and find a match in the very first iteration of the `while` loop, and thereby save maybe 10 useless iterations that you would otherwise still do using the alternative code that does not include this `if`. This may seem a good thing.

But, statistically, if the value *is* in the list, you'll have like a 50% change to only find it in the last possible iteration (when the range is just 1 wide). And if the value is *not* in the list, you will certainly have to perform all iterations. So it makes sense to make each iteration do as *little* as possible. And that is the reason *not* to include that `if` statement *in* the loop, but only execute it once, after the loop.

To choose what is the best strategy for your case, implement them both, and do a benchmark comparison based on realistic data and searches.

Comment: A great, thoughtful answer, but I wonder if there's more consensus about ranges than stated. Isn't it fair to say, in the most common tools, that ranges exclude their max parameter, arrays are indexed from 0 to n-1 and that loops test `< n` more commonly than `<= n-1`?

Comment: @danh I have asked about 30 people (job candidates) to write a binary search, and all but 2 of the successful ones used an inclusive range, and every single one used a ternary condition.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - I just found a bsearch I had lying around, and I'm now embarrassed to admit that it tests for the pointers crossing with `<=`.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that in most common tools, ranges exclude their max parameter. But there are language environments that deviate from that. For instance, if in VBA you declare `Dim arr(5)`, then the array has an index 5. And a basic `For i = 1 To 10` loop will include an iteration with `i=10`. We may criticise this pattern, but in such a language environment it would make sense to remain consistent with it. But like in c-style languages, it makes more sense to have an exclusive max parameter.